# Missing values show broken line in Lens

Tags: kibana, kibana-7

I have an application that dumps statistics once every minute into ElasticSearch. Using Kibana, I've created a lens to visualize the values over time. All good.

Occasionally, the application skips a dump (which is a separate issue I'll be working on), so I may have occasional missing values. In the Lens, the Line chart breaks the line when a value is missing for a certain time (see screenshot).

[image: Broken line chart]

How can I interpolate between the available values and show a continuous line instead?

**EDIT**

To make it clear, I'm asking how to fix the chart in the Lens. The issue of skipped dumps is a separate one and needs to be addressed separately. I may still have some missing values (unlikely but not impossible), and I would like my Lens to show a continuous chart anyway.

**UPDATE**

While I found the "Missing values" setting in "Visual Options" and I set it to "Linear", the interpolation is rendered with a dashed line. How can I make it the same as the main line?

Comment: Is this programming related?

Comment: Oops, sorry! Is there a different SE for Kibana or data visualization?

Comment: I have no idea. Have you checked here? https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology

Comment: I'd think Kibana belongs here, since there's several tags about it.

Comment: SO is for programming questions and the fact there are others doesn't legitimate an off-topic question